# Ajax calls wrong method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my method:

```
function logOff() {
    $.ajax({ url: "Login/LogOff", type: "GET", success: function (data) { window.location.href = "Login/Index"; } })//end of ajax call
}
```

With this, I want the action method LogOff in the LoginController to be called. However, what is called is: http://localhost:6355/Home/Login/LogOff and I get error. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
if (data == "") {
    patharray = window.location.href.split('/');
    data = window.location.protocol + "//" + patharray[2];
}
window.location.href = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put one extra slash in the begining of your `url` value. This is called **relative** URL.

```
function logOff() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Login/LogOff", // <-- slash before "Login"
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "/Login/Index"; // <-- slash before "Login"
        }
    })
}
```

Another option is to use *absolute* URL:

```
url: "http://localhost:6355/Login/LogOff"
```

But it is not flexible.

Comment: You didn't understand. The problem is in the url parameter, not in the success part.

Comment: @Srcee: *The very same* problem is in the url parameter.

Comment: @VisioN It's not that. The same thing happens.

Comment: Since this is in MVC.NET, it might be pointed out that it would be neater to use the `UrlHelper` for both `location.href` and `url`. If the code is in a JS file where `UrlHelper` is not available, they could be passed from a context where it is available, e.g. `var urls = { logout: '<%= Url.Action("LogOff", "Login") %>', home: '<%= Url.Action("Index", "Login") %>' };`

Comment: @DavidHedlund Assuming that it might be JS file I did not mention about `UrlHelper`. Otherwise, it is a good issue!